# SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow does not resumes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint 2013 designer workflow. it has an action "Wait for Item Update". Workflow does not resumes when i update the item through Code(C#) but when item is updated from out of the box edit form it resumes.

> SPList listUpdate = web.Lists["Registration"];
>   SPListItemCollection items = listUpdate.GetItems(new SPQuery()
>   {
>   Query = @"" + Convert.ToString(newItemid) + ""
>   });
>   web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
>   items[0]["Title"] = "1";
>   items[0].Update();
>   web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, one wonders if you executed the query?

```
class UpdateListItem
{
    static void Main()
    {   
        string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");
        ListItem oListItem = oList.Items.GetById(3);

        oListItem["Title"] = "My Updated Title.";

        oListItem.Update();

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry my bad i didn't give you full info

i am currently using Server side object model

`SPList listUpdate = web.Lists["Registration"];

SPListItemCollection items = listUpdate.GetItems(new SPQuery()
{
 Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + Convert.ToString(newItemid) + "</Value></Eq></Where>"
  });
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
items[0]["Title"] = "1";
items[0].Update();
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;`

Comment: @MohammadMavia I don't see that you fire the query. You leave it at update() and no clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: And if you try the pasted code in the answer? Does that work?

Comment: see i am not using Client Side Object Model (CSOM)
i am using server side object model
it doesn't nee clientContext.ExecuteQuery()